# boot2docker host bind mount volume size limited to 1.8 GB

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm playing with volume containers on boot2docker to run Docker on MacOS X.

```
boot2docker version
Client version: v1.2.0
Git commit: a551732
```

I'm trying to perform the backup/restore process which is mentioned in [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes).

**I'm trying to backup a MySQL database which is over 2 GB**. When I run the backup command:

```
docker run --volumes-from data_volume -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/mysql
```

**...if fails with this error**:

```
tar: /backup/backup.tar: Wrote only 4096 of 10240 bytes
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

**It seems `tar` is out of disk space**. So I got into my container and looked at **the host bind mount and its size is 1.8 GB**.

```
docker run -t -i -v $HOME:/demo ubuntu /bin/bash
root@bb3921a48ba4:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           19G  8.3G  9.1G  48% /
none             19G  8.3G  9.1G  48% /
tmpfs          1005M     0 1005M   0% /dev
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        19G  8.3G  9.1G  48% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           1.8G  1.8G     0 100% /demo
tmpfs          1005M     0 1005M   0% /proc/kcore
```

*You can see that `/demo` is only 1.8G...*

I don't know how to extend this size so I would be able to make large backups...

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this sneaking feeling that you're running out of memory - as 2GB is the default amount of ram we allocate.

Rather than writing to a file, mapped to a virtual filesystem that is attached to your OSX box's FS, I'd suggest running the tar to output to STDOUT, and then pipe that to your local box.

ie

`docker run --rm  ubuntu tar cf - /etc > test.tar`

Comment: Is there any way to share a folder with the OSX host, that doesn't take up RAM on the virtualbox VM? Or is that a bottleneck for everything?